# Autopep8 and pre-commit not honoring --global-config

Tags: python, autopep8, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to use pre-commit with autopep8 running the command `pre-commit run --all-files`. My tree and files are as follows:

```
.
├── project
│   ├── ...
├── docs
│   ├── ...
│   └── conf.py
├── .flake8
├── .pre-commit-config.yaml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── tox.ini
```

In `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-autopep8
    rev: v1.4.4
    hooks:
    -   id: autopep8
```

In `.flake8`:

```
[flake8]
exclude=.git,__pycache__,docs/conf.py,build,dist
...
```

However when I run `pre-commit run --all-files`, my .flake8 file wasn't getting picked up, so I tried adding --global-config to .flake8:

```
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-autopep8
    rev: v1.4.4
    hooks:
    -   id: autopep8
        args: [--global-config, .flake8]
```

but that just results in an error:

```
autopep8: error: autopep8 only takes one filename as argument unless the "--in-place" or "--diff" args are used
```

What am I doing wrong?

My pre-commit version is 1.18.2.

Comment: Relates to https://stackoverflow.com/q/55172676/7619676, which hasn’t really been answered yet

Comment: Answered on the github issue -- the answer is roughly a duplicate to the linked question above: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-autopep8/issues/2